# Eloquent recursive self join in addition to another table join

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

Frist, sorry for the not so clear title, I hope I can explain it better here:

I have a MenuItem model which has recursive self join to represent multilevel menu. In addition, the menu item actually might have a foreign key to Post model. The model is like this:

```
class MenuItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function parentItem()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MenuItem::class, 'parent_menu_id', 'id');
    }

    public function childrenItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MenuItem::class, 'parent_menu_id', 'id');
    }

    public function allChildrenItems()
    {
        return $this->childrenItems()->with('allChildrenItems');
    }

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

to retrieve all menu items recursively I do this and it works perfectly:

```
$menu = MenuItem::with('allChildrenItems')->whereNull('parent_menu_id')->get();
```

I had to add the condition `whereNull` to retrieve first only the top level menu items, and the recursive join will bring the rest of items based on the hirarchy.

The problem is that I also need to join every menu item with the proper post. I tried to update the above eloquent query to be like this:

```
$menu = MenuItem::with('allChildrenItems')->whereNull('parent_menu_id')
                ->leftJoin('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'menu_items.post_id')
                ->get();
```

But that left join only works for the top level collection `whereNull('parent_menu_id')`, and will not be resented in the recursive join (the children menu items).

How can I add a join to both parent and children items here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `parentItem` and `childrenItems` relationship, add `with('post')` to it so that post will be added to every level.

```
public function parentItem()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MenuItem::class, 'parent_menu_id', 'id')
        ->with('post');
}

public function childrenItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MenuItem::class, 'parent_menu_id', 'id')
        ->with('post');
}
```

Comment: Wow! It worked! Are we allowed to do that? Is it something we can do in a common way?

Comment: to tell you the truth, I haven't tried it myself but logically this is the way it's supposed to work so other than that I can't tell with confidence.

Comment: all hails laravel creator and contributors!